# Array Element's Index is False

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

In my code, I'm trying to map through an array and find an element. Then, I will replace that element with a string. The problem is, the `index` is -1. And, wrong element is replaced with the string. What is the cause of this problem and how can I fix this? My stackblitz and code is down below.

JS:

```
const arr = ['this', 'is', '<a/>', 'apple'];
const index = arr.indexOf(arr.includes('<'));
console.log(index);

const newArray = arr.map((arrayElement) => {
  arr.splice(index, 1, 'blocked');
  return arrayElement;
});

console.log(newArray);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-z6cpdd?file=index.js%3AL9

Comment: `includes('<' || '>' || '/'`)` is not how you use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Instead of using splice, return different values.

Comment: so, after the edit you're effectively doing `array.indexOf(true)` or `array.indexOf(false)` since `includes` returns either `true` or `false`

Comment: `<a/>` makes me think that you are trying to manipulate some HTML content. Could be an XY Problem

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of issues. If you want to supply multiple strings to [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), you need to call `includes` multiple times, and you need to call it on the string values, not the array. In your scenario it's easier to use a regex [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a character class in [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). Secondly, you can simply call [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) on the array (noting that it changes the original array), instead of using `map`:

```js
const arr = ['this', 'is', '<a/>', 'apple'];
const index = arr.findIndex(s => s.match(/[<>/]/));

arr.splice(index, 1, 'blocked');

console.log(arr);
```